# Tags hovering like Stack Overflow using jQuery

Tags: jquery, tags, mousehover

How does stackoverflow does that hovering effect on a tag of a question? How to do the same using jquery?

EDIT:
Not that mouseover i want the submenu showing `Add Jquery to favorite tags`

Comment: it could be done with just simple CSS, why need jQuery?

Comment: nice attitude you got there...

Comment: @Reigel if you use the hover tags on CSS only, then lots of mobile devices will not be able to access them due to their lack of functional support for the hover attribute.

Comment: Shripad seems to have answered your question...don't forget to mark his answer as accepted if it works for you!

Comment: @Jaryl if mobile devices is the reason to use javascript for something that should be done just with css (in my opinion), it would make more sense to use a mobile device specific css that doesn't use hover.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This should do the work.

http://jsfiddle.net/5GD6r/4/

I have coded it almost exactly the way Stack Overflow does. I built upon the button already created by @Reigel.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged 'mousehover'" rel="tag">Ruby-on-Rails</a>

<a href="#" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged 'mousehover'" rel="tag">JQuery</a>

<a href="#" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged 'mousehover'" rel="tag">CSS</a>


<div class="mouseoverHoverBox">
    <span class="pointer">
        <span class="plusminus">+</span>
        <span class="addRemove">Add </span>
        <span class="insert"></span>
        <span class="fromTo"> To </span>
        <span>Interesting tags</span>
    </span>
    <br />
    <span class="pointer">
        <span class="plusminus">+</span>
        <span class="addRemove">Add</span>
        <span class="insert"></span>
        <span class="fromTo"> To </span>
        <span>Ignored tags</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

---

CSS:

```
.post-tag {
    position:relative;
    background-color: #E0EAF1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #3E6D8E;
    border-right: 1px solid #7F9FB6;
    color: #3E6D8E;
    font-size: 90%;
    line-height: 2.4;
    margin: 2px 0px 2px 0px;
    padding: 3px 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    }

.post-tag:hover {
    position:relative;
    background-color:#3E6D8E;
    color:#E0EAF1;
    border-bottom:1px solid #37607D;
    border-right:1px solid #37607D;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.mouseoverHoverBox {
    position:relative;
    top: -6px;
    border: 2px ridge #CCC;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 250px;
}

.plusminus {
    color: #E45C0E;
}

.pointer {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #3E6D8E;
}
```

---

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('.mouseoverHoverBox').hide();

$('.post-tag').live('mouseover',function(e){
    var x = $(this).offset();
    $('.mouseoverHoverBox').css('left',x.left-10);
    $('.insert').html(' <b>'+$(this).text() + '</b> ');
    $('.mouseoverHoverBox').slideDown();
});

$('.pointer').live('mouseover mouseout', function(e){
    if(e.type=="mouseover") {
        $(this).css('text-decoration','underline');
    }else if(e.type="mouseout") {
        $(this).css('text-decoration','none');
    }
});

$('.pointer').toggle(function() {
   $(this).find('.plusminus').text('x ');
   $(this).find('.addRemove').text('Remove ');
   $(this).find('.fromTo').text('From');
}, function() {
   $(this).find('.plusminus').text('+ ');
   $(this).find('.addRemove').text('Add ');
   $(this).find('.fromTo').text('To');
});

$('.mouseoverHoverBox').mouseleave(function(){
     $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For a simple hover effect you really should use `css`, like

```
a.hover:hover {
   background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

for instance.

If it **must** be in jQuery, it would look like

```
$('a.myanchorclass').hover(function(){
     $(this).css('background-color', '#ff0000');
}, function(){
     $(this).css('background-color', '#000000');
});
```

Comment: I can't see why this is downvoted, seems like a perfectly valid solution?

Answer (score -1):

I agree with both just to emphasize, you absolutely can use the :hover in CSS, if you are targeting browsers newer then IE6, IE6 won't work with :hover unless it's a link.